# What does double arrow function mean in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I have the code below but I don't understand the double arrow notation, does the second arrow function work if the first one's response is true? When this notation used?

```
  async check({ commit }) {
     await axios.get('check')
     .then((response) => {
      console.log("try");
     }, (response) => {
      console.log("try2");
     }

     return true;
     });
```

Comment: it's just an another way of defining a function. It is introduced in ES6

Comment: This is a question about promises, not arrow functions.

Comment: @tadman - This is a question about promises, not arrow functions, despite appearances.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I suppose it could be read as "double" arrow, as in *two* arrow functions.

Comment: @tadman - Exactly. :-)

Comment: The function quoted doesn't make a lot of sense, and has syntax errors...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with arrow functions. It has to do with the `then` method on promises.

With a promise's `then` method, the first argument is a *fulfillment handleer* and the second is a *rejection handler*. If the promise is fulfilled, the first is called with the fulfillment value. If the promise is rejected, the second is called with the rejection reason. Only one or the other (if either) will be called, never both (for the same promise).

Here's a slightly edited version of the function partially shown in the qusetion, with some names changed and the `return true;` removed (because I couldn't figure out where it was meant to be):

```
async check({ commit }) {
    await axios.get('check')
    .then(
        (value) => {                       // ***
            // Use the fulfillment value   // *** fulfillment handler
        },                                 // ***

        (reason) => {                      // ***
            // Deal with the rejection     // *** rejection handler
        }                                  // ***
    );
});
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or the [Promises A+ specification](https://promisesaplus.com/) that JavaScript's promises are based on.

---

It's probably worth noting that there's no particular reason to make *this specific function* an `async` function unless the goal is specifically to hide any fulfillment value the promise may have (or the rejection handler may supply). It does that, though, so perhaps that's the purpose.

Comment: FWIW, I cover promises in a fair bit of detail (including the difference between `.then(fn1, fn2)` and `.then(fn1).catch(fn2)`) in Chapter 8 of my new book (and `async`/`await` in Chapter 9); links in my profile if you're interested.

Answer (score 2):

The [Promises/A+ standard](https://promisesaplus.com) says that [`then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) can take two arguments:

```
promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)
```

The second one is the `onRejected` handler.

You don't see this as often since `catch()` exists, but it's still part of the standard.